# ASP:Menu is not properly working in IIS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, aspmenu

I have an asp menu which is working great in debug mode but when website is published it does not work in IIS.
Below is working fine in Visual Studio 2010 Debug mode:

[image: This menu is working fine in VS 2010 Debug mode]

But child menu not appear when hover on this menu in IIS:

[image]
Here is html code & css.

```
<div id="menu">
           <asp:Menu id="Menu1" Orientation="Horizontal" Runat="server" 
                OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
           </asp:Menu>
</div>

#menu {  }
#menu a 
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #B79845 !important;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: David;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000000;
    height: 18px;
    width: 183px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    margin: 0 3px 0 0;
    background-color: #B79845;
    color: #303822;
    font-weight: 900;
    height: 18px;
    width: 183px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a user permission issue, that is, use does not have the right permission to expand that menu?

Comment: looks like some CSS is missing probably. Check that everything was deployed properly and also check the file permissions that the server can serve it.

Comment: @LenielMacaferi User has all the rights ... it is wokring absolutely fine in Debug mode of Visual Studio but not working when published in IIS...